# Why does my S3 static website “Access Denied” only in certain areas?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I created a CloudFront distribution to serve a static website. The website works perfectly where I am, and I have had several people attempt to access the website and it works.

When I use a VPN to access the site in other locations the webpage returns “Access Denied”. I configured the bucket policy to allow anonymous get requests and made the bucket public.

I am unsure why it cannot be accessed in some areas.

I do not have geo-restriction enabled.

Comment: How have you configured DNS?

Comment: To where does the VPN connect?

Comment: You are getting access denied can you add screenshot. This will help us to understand whether is AWS error or VPN security error.

Comment: I could not figure out specifically why the error occurred, but to fix this I created an entirely new cloudfront distribution and pointed by sub domain to my root domain in AWS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this error I pointed the subdomain "www.example.com" to "example.com" in route 53. I then created a new CF distribution for the root name. Prior I had a CF distribution for the both the subdomain and root domain.